# How to "reset" subviews of scrollview for new items?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, subview

I have a MasterViewController displaying Items. Selecting an Item (ItemA), displays images of ItemA in a DetailViewController. The DeatilViewController contains a scrollView, displaying all the images.

When tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called, the images is added to an UIImageView, that is tagged and added as a subview to a scrollview.

```
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++)
{
     NSString *imageName = [ItemAImages objectAtIndex:i-1];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
     imageView.tag = i; 
     [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Works fine. But when I go back to the MasterViewController, and selects a ItemB, the ItemA is still displayed, like the iPhone simulator refuses to forget the previous scrollview,containing ItemA images. I have tried

```
for(UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews])
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

which results in either no scrollview at all, or no effect. Depending on when this method is called.
How can I "reset" the scrollview for the next Item?

Comment: The easiest way is to replace it with a new scrollview for the new items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove every subview of your scrollview.

So you have to call `removeFromSuperview` not on the `scrollView` itself but on each and every of its subviews.

Be careful when you do that as your array of subviews (returned by `scrollview.subviews`) is going to change while you iterate thru it and remove the subviews. So better make a copy of this list of subviews and iterate on that copy:

```
NSArray* subviews = [scrollview.subviews copy];
for(UIView* v in subviews)
{
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
[subviews release];
```

---

*Note: Always avoid to modify the collection over which you are iterating. Also because you will risk to skip some objects in your enumeration. For exemple if you have an array `@[A,B,C,D,E]` and iterate over the content to remove the objects, your code will probably say "remove the object at index 0, then the object at index 1, then the one at index 2…. But once you have remove the object at index 0, the collection would have changed to `@[B,C,D,E]` and the array at index 1 would be C, not B which you would then have skipped. And once you removed object at index 1, your collection will have become `@[B,D,E]` and removing object at index 2 next will result in `@[B,D]`…
I don't know if that's the cause of your problem, that makes you miss some subviews, but if you did it that way it probably explains why it didn't work properly.*

Comment: Thanks. But the problem i still there. Either the images are never displayed, or the same iamages are reappearing. Maybe it the problem is when this method is beeing called. viewDidUnload does not work. Neither viewWillUnload works.

Comment: Thank you for a very good answere. I just wonder; When the copy is made and the copy is removed from supeview, what then happens with the original?

Comment: When the copy is made, you will have 2 independent arrays containing the same UIViews in them. When you remove each view from their superview (aka the scrollview), they are no longer retained by the scrollview itself as you removed them from the view hierarchy, but they are still retained by the copy. So if you query the `scrollview.subviews` property they won't be in that array anymore, neither on screen, but they will still be retained in the copied array you iterate over. Finally when you release the copied array the views won't be retained anymore and will be deallocated.